# OpenProcess returns access_denied on 64 bit platform

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit

I have a function:

```
HANDLE snapshot=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

...

result=Process32First(snapshot,&pe);
while(result) {
  if(!_stricmp(process_name,pe.szExeFile)) {
    processes.push_back(pe.th32ProcessID);
  }
  result=Process32Next(snapshot,&pe);
}

for(dword_vector::iterator i=processes.begin(); i!=processes.end(); ++i){
  HANDLE hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, *i);
  if(hProcess) {
    TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  }
}
```

It works fine on 32bit platform but on 64 bit platform OpenProcess returns Access_denied for some processes(the same processes on 32 bit can be computed fine). All processes I trying to open are 32bit.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Is there any chance that the process to be killed behaves differently on 32- and 64-bit platforms ? Do you run it under a debugger ? It could open the door to problems like http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx (plus: see SkyWing's comment) or http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/64494fdb44a560eb.

Comment: Or have you noticed some characteristic common to the processes that do not let themselves be killed ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the user you are logged in on the 64-bit platform does not have the rights to terminate those processes ? e.g. on Vista, UAC is active, you are an admin but not running elevated and trying to close system processes.

Comment: Oh, and it seems that OpenProcess() would have failed in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

This might be really out there, but are you executing the code from a **network** drive? I've seen .NET applications fail to do very basic things when run from a network drive.

If you are, try moving the executable to a local disk and see if that helps.

Yes, I know this is a very weird suggestion, I just figure if that's the problem it might help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a 64-bit process or a 32-bit process?  You can't open a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process.

Use task manager to make sure your application is 64-bit.  If not, fix and compile it as 64-bit and you should be able to open other 64-bit processes and 32-bit processes.

If your app is 32-bit, it is probably a permissions problem.  Try running it as Administrator and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: That is incorrect, it is very well supported and possible to open 64-bit processes from 32-bit processes. Please don't answer questions unless you have sufficient knowledge in the domain. There are some restrictions, e.g. protected OS processes as well as some API calls that work only for 32 bit but not 64 bit processes. But it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same assumption with the op. After doing many tests, I know the reason for access_denied proccesses is that they are under SYSTEM user, not because they are 64 bit.